# How to remove dist files in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I want to deploy my angular project i generated dist file in my src folder like this

```
ng build
```

Before deploying I decided to add some functionality to my page :

**Question**
Is it posible to update dist files by doing like this?

```
ng serve update /dist dir
```

if false I want to delete the dist file and create another one so that it can be update with all folders, this is what I wanna do

```
ng serve remove /dist dir
```

Is this the right way of removing dist files ?

Comment: Why don't you just `ng build` again? `serve` is in-memory, so that won't help.

Comment: Do ng build again. Old ones will be replaced

Comment: As jonrsharpe implied, `ng serve` doesn't generate the `/dist` since it serves the vendor, styles, pollyfills, and main in memory.

Comment: @jonrsharpe its not that is easy I would not ask here if was that simple : I get this error : 
`ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\Bonge\Documents\Projects\movies_database\movies-client\dist\movies-client'
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\Bonge\Documents\Projects\movies_database\movies-client\dist\movies-client'
    at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:846:18)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I asked here just be sure what is the best way to remove dist with messing other issue otherwise I could just delete usingt cmd

Comment: It's useful to describe the actual problem you're having in the question; please [edit] accordingly. If you're having a problem with the functionality provided by the Angular CLI, it might be better to look in their issue tracker on GitHub to see if other people have the same one. But you certainly can't just invent commands like `ng serve remove` and expect them to magically work. You could simply delete the folder manually *then* build again.

Comment: That is the option I am going to do , I just wanted to be sure am new to all this stuf thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution on Windows

```
rd /s dist
```

and on Linux

```
rm -r dist
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a flag for this. See [angular.io/cli/build](http://angular.io/cli/build)

```
--delete-output-path true
```

I use

```
"build:dev": "ng build --configuration dev --delete-output-path true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using package.json AND to be operating system safe I recommend rimraf. It's not only about Windows vs Linux. Also about Linux Distribution vs Linux Distribution, changing access rights, etc. You are safe with this extra layer of abstraction.

Install:

```
npm install rimraf
```

In your scripts section of package.json add it as first command and append what ever you want to do after the `&&`:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "rimraf /dist && ng build"
}
```

Invoke the build/serve:

```
npm run ng
```

`ng` is what you defined as your script execution identifier.